# AsyncTask or threads

Tags: android

In my app, activity A connects to server database retaining Latitude and Longitude from different cities and activity B connects to google maps directions calculating distances between cities. The results are shown via List adapter.

1. Because there are a couple of distances to be calculate every time (20 -30), which is the fastest way to achieve this; Using many times AsyncTask or using threads;
2. Should i merge these two activities to speed up work; ( But then, i am facing problems because FragmentActivity, the extending class of activity B doesn't support List adapter

Thanks

Comment: You do know that AsyncTask uses threads right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with threads. That's why i'm asking

Comment: There are only two ways to execute concurrent instruction, one is using Process and another is using Thread. I recommend you read [this article.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html)

Comment: @Paulo I could be wrong but I believe the Android equivalent of a Process is Service

Comment: AsyncTasks are easy, but they run one at a time -- if you want them running in parallel, you'll need to provide an Executor.  Threads are less easy, but provide a lot more flexibility. Keep usage limits in mind as you develop this.

Comment: @JonathanKramer A process is always called by OS through main() method. So everything called by OS is a process. A Thread is different, because it is called by a process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Multithreading

I personally like AsyncTasks because they are a clean way to handle multithreading. (Note that AsyncTasks are running on separate threads in the doInBackground() part)

However, if you think the workload is too intensive for the AsyncTask than the android developer guide recommends you use a background Service instead.

To me it seems like you might be able to a sequence of two asynctasks: the first grabs the lat/long values from the server in doInBackground(). In the first's onPostExecute() you can start the second, giving it the server values. The second can then calculate the distance in its doInBackground() method.

2) Activities and ListAdapter

Combine both activities into one for sure. Even though FragmentActivity obviously can't be a ListActivity, you can still pull out your ListView from xml with

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Or programmatically create a list view with

```
ListView list = new ListView(this);
```

Then you can instantiate whatever type of adapter class you want and set it to the ListView. The following example show this using a CursorAdapter but this will work with any adapter, custom or built in.

```
    CursorAdapter dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity(), R.layout.list_spot,
            cursor,
            columns,
            to,
            0);

    list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: to the person who down voted this do you care to explain why for everyones sake